# I want to import only those rows that meet the conditions of the same numbered row

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is:

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM 
    (SELECT
         ig_idx,
         --, count(ig_root) over(partition by ig_root) AS GameCount1
         ig_root,
         ig_game_type,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ig_root
                            ORDER BY CASE WHEN ig_game_type IN ('12', '1x2') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ig_game_type ASC) AS seqnum
     FROM 
         Info_Game) AS t
ORDER BY 
    ig_root, seqnum
```

Of the same number of ig_root, seqnum = 1 and type = '12' or type = '1x2'
I want to get it ig_root of same number

```
ig_idx  ig_root ig_game_type  seqnum
1       11      12            1
2       11      ah            2
3       11      ou            3
4       12      12            1
5       13      1h_ah         1  <--- this 
9       13      1h_ou         2
6       13      2h_ou         3
7       13      ah            4
8       13      ou            5
10      14      1x2           1
11      14      1h_ah         2
14      14      1h_ou         3
12      14      h             4
13      14      ou            5
```

idx 5 : This means that seqnum is 1, 
but the type is not 12 or 1x2. 
So I do not want to bring ig_root  number 13.

like this:

```
ig_idx  ig_root ig_game_type  seqnum
1       11      12            1
2       11      ah            2
3       11      ou            3
4       12      12            1
10      14      1x2           1
11      14      1h_ah         2
14      14      1h_ou         3
12      14      h             4
13      14      ou            5
```

Comment: Given your desired results, why can't you just do: `where ig_root <> 13`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter to get only the ig_root that have 1x2 or 12

```
WHERE ig_root IN (SELECT ig_root FROM Info_Game WHERE ig_game_type IN ('1x2', '12')
```